# How to display API received data as a Bar Chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, bar-chart

I can display my API data fine and I know how to display data in a bar chart format when using `PHP` to retrieve the data from a database. With these two in mind, I would like to apply the API data to the bar chart. However, I am unsure how to do this. I have tried to apply the `API` results to the graph but nothing worked so I am sorry but if anyone could apply this code for me, that would be great!

I want to display the API as such:

Year: 2017

Estimated Pay: (Bar chart) with the price (estpay) still being there

Here is the code that is used to display my API data

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.series.length; i++) {
                            $("<span>", {
                                class: "espYear",
                                text: `Year: ${data.series[i].year}`
                            }).appendTo($data);
                            $("<span>", {
                                class: "espPay",
                                text: `Pay per week: £${data.series[i].estpay}`
                            }).appendTo($data);
                        }
```

This is my bar chart code that I used with PHP, but I want to apply the code above with this below.

```
var data = {
  "summary": [{
    "name": "Train:",
    "hits": <?php echo $num_rows; ?>
  }]
};
var element;
for (element in data.summary) {
  var names = data.summary[element].name;
  var values2 = data.summary[element].hits;

  var node = document.createElement("tr");
  var subnode1 = document.createElement("td");
  var textnode1 = document.createTextNode(names);
  var subnode2 = document.createElement("td");
  var textnode2 = document.createTextNode(values2);
  var subnode3 = document.createElement("td");
  var subsubnode = document.createElement("canvas");

  subnode1.appendChild(textnode1);
  subnode2.appendChild(textnode2);
  subnode3.appendChild(subsubnode);

  var att = subsubnode.setAttribute("id", names);
  var att2 = subsubnode.setAttribute("width", "800");
  var att3 = subsubnode.setAttribute("height", "25");

  node.appendChild(subnode1);
  node.appendChild(subnode2);
  node.appendChild(subnode3);
  document.getElementById("chart").appendChild(node);

  var c = document.getElementById(names);
  var bar = c.getContext("2d");
  var length = values2;
  if (values2 > 0) {
    if (length > 100)
      length = 100;
    bar.fillStyle = "#ADD9EC"; //"blue";
  }

  bar.rect(1, 1, 10 * <?php echo $num_rows; ?>, 20);
  bar.fill();
  bar.stroke()

}
```

Comment: User https://www.highcharts.com

Comment: @FaseehHaris yes i know of this site, and as you can see i already have the bar chart